# Can we bind all types of Google Guice module(s) only once in the application?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

```
public interface Tweeter {
 public void sendTweet(String message);
}

public class SmsTweeter implements Tweeter {
@Override
public void sendTweet(String message) {
    System.out.println("You SMS tweet: "+message);
}
}

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

public class TweetModule extends AbstractModule{

@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(Tweeter.class).to(SmsTweeter.class);       
}
}

import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;

public class TestTweetClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new TweetModule());
    Tweeter tweeter = injector.getInstance(Tweeter.class);
    tweeter.sendTweet("Hi there");
}
}
```

Whenever I will call `Guice.createInjector`, the configure() method of my module will run. And it will bind my types.

Can we make this configure method to run only once in the application? (e.g: in startup servlet of a web app)

What is the point of running this configure method every time?

Comment: Normally, you will only call `createInjector`one time, when you're bootstrapping your application.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [ServletModule](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule) if you are developing web application.